# Semantic versioning automation

Tags: git, continuous-integration, issue-tracking, semantic-versioning

After I've read [this article](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/12/10/semantic-versioning-with-continuous-deployment/) and another ones, I figure out **versioning is a programmer decision**, so I believe CI system isn't able to understand which's version of this package (**CI system isn't able to understand whether the pulled commit is a patch, a new feature**).

However, **a programmer isn't able to know how to link the patch (bug, feature and so on) to a release built number identification**.

According to semantic versioning:

- increment the patch version (e.g. from 2.3.4 to 2.3.5) when you only release bug fixes and the like
- increment the minor version (e.g. from 1.3.2 to 1.4.0) when you add new features
- increment the major version (e.g. from 3.2.9 to 4.0.0) when you introduce breaking changes

My semantic verion is going to follow next pattern: `1.2.3+7489ab44d3`, where 1 is MAJOR version number, 2 is MINOR version number and 3 is patch or bug number. then the `+7489ab44d3` will be the built job identification on CI system.

So, the first part of this pattern depends of an human brain and the last one is under a CI system.

I've read also, it would be possible to use an issue tracker system in order to sort out each issue under a some kind of information and provide it to CI system.

Which is the best way for providing an automation in order to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

We are using plugin to do it.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Version+Number+Plugin

We know what is the version based upon the branch name and based upon it we generate the appropriate build number.

Its a separate task in the build procedure and you can achieve it with several systems and plugins.

Comment: As far I've been able to figure out, this plugin is useful for providing a version number for your build according to several provided format strings. However, this plugin doesn't know how to change from 2.4.x to 2.5.x, because CI (Jenkins) doesn't know whether the pulled commit solves a bug or provides a new feature. In .Net projects it's important to tag assemblies with a version number, how this plugin is able to change the content a file (`AssemblyInfo.cs`) before of building it? Or how to change the version content of a license file? This changes are programmer decission, IMHO.

Comment: You are right. for this we use a script which pass parameters to the build to "change" the "major" release

Comment: Which kind of script are you using? When and where is it performed?

Comment: We have a special software for that purpose which is being called in one of our Jenkins build steps.

Comment: As a "special software" you mean a custom-made software? If is that, could you explain me a short description it's doing?